# why python __dict__ doesnot inherit class attribute but can access it

Tags: python, class

```
class A(object):
    name = "Class A"

class B(A):
    pass
print A.__dict__
print B.__dict__
```

output:

```
{'__dict__': <attribute '__dict__' of 'A' objects>, '__module__': '__main__', '_
_weakref__': <attribute '__weakref__' of 'A' objects>, 'name': 'Class A', '__doc
__': None}


{'__module__': '__main__', '__doc__': None}
```

The attr 'name' was not in B.**dict**, but can access by 'B.name'.

```
print B.name
```

output:

```
B.name =  Class A
```

I am still confused what's the difference between `getattr` function and `Class.__dict__`.

Answer (score 3):

`B.__dict__` is only the things defined directly on `B`.  When you try to access an attribute, a dynamic lookup process takes place, whereby the superclasses are tried in order to see which (if any) has the attribute.

Comment: Note that an instantiation of `A` will also not have `name` in `__dict__`, but does have any attributes that are set in `__init__`. This behavior is also explained by your dynamic lookup answer.